# Vetor struct e ponteiros

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, array, struct

Tenho q pegar dados (nome e telefone) de algumas pessoas em uma `struct`, depois armazena-las em um vetor, tudo isso por uma função/procedimento. Nna hora de imprimir sai uns caracteres estranhos.

Estou usando a plataforma DEV C++

```
# include <stdio.h> 
# include <stdlib.h> 

#define MAX 2

typedef struct dadosPessoais    
    { 
        char nome = ' ';
        int telefone = -1;
    }DadosPessoais; 

void inserir(DadosPessoais *vetor);
void listar(DadosPessoais *vetor);

int main()
{

    int escolha=1;
    DadosPessoais vetor[MAX];

// se a escolha for diferente de 3, ele continua... o que inicialmente é verdade
// pois escolha é igual a 1

    while (escolha!=5)
    {

        printf("\n\n ----------------------- ");

        printf("\n 1 - Inserir novo registro ");
        printf("\n 2 - Limpar registros da tabela ");
        printf("\n 3 - Fechar Programa ");
        printf("\n\n Escolha uma opcao: ");
        scanf("%d",&escolha);


// estrutura switch
        switch (escolha)
         {

            case 1:
            {
                system ("cls");
                inserir(vetor);
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                system ("cls");
                listar(vetor);
                break;
            }   

// opção padrão
            default:
            {
                system ("cls");

// se for escolhida a opção 3, ele pula o while utilizando continue para isso 
                if( escolha==3)
                {
                    continue;
                }
// caso o usuário digite um numero acima de 5, ele irá informar que nao existe essa opção
                printf("\n\n Nenhuma opcao foi escolhida ");
                break;
            }
        }   

    }
    if( escolha==3)
    printf("\n\n O Programa foi fechado");

    system("PAUSE"); 

}

void inserir(DadosPessoais *vetor)
{
    int x=3, i, espaco ;

    for(i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        if (vetor[i].nome == ' ')
        {
            espaco = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            espaco = 2;
        }       

    }

    if (espaco == 1)
    {
        printf("Digite nome: \n");
        scanf(" %s", &vetor->nome);

        printf("Digite o telefone: \n ");
        scanf(" %d", &vetor->telefone);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Nao ha espaco vago \n ");
    }
}

void listar(DadosPessoais *vetor)
{
    int x=MAX, i, espaco ;

    for(i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        if (vetor[i].nome != ' ')
        {
            printf(" %c", &vetor[x].nome);
            printf("\n");
            printf(" %c", &vetor[x].telefone);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Vetor vazio");
        }       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta poderia ser considera muita ampla porque tem diversos problemas. O Stack Overflow funciona melhor com problemas bem definidos em perguntas bem focadas.

Vou listar alguns problemas do seu código que precisar ser corrigidos. A partir daí você vai poder melhorar algumas coisas e poder fazer perguntas mais focadas quando tiver um problema mais específico.

1. O tipo `char` armazena apenas um caractere. Para armazenar vários caracteres você precisa declarar como *array*, algo como `char nome[40]` onde você reservará 40 caracteres dentro da própria `struct` que é bem ineficiente para pode ser usado para fins didáticos. Ou pode declarar como `char * nome` e pode ter o tamanho indeterminado, ocupando apenas o espaço para um ponteiro (aí terá que fazer a alocação fora).
2. Você não inicializa o vetor. Por isso é muito fácil pegar muito lixo. O fato de você reservar memória para a variável na declaração não quer dizer que a memória é limpa.
3. Você está usando um inteiro para guardar telefone. Apesar de um número de telefone parecer um valor numérico ele não é. Eu usaria uma *string* para isto também. Lembrando que se insistir em usar um `int`, não poderá usar números com mais que 9 dígitos ou que comecem com zero (que tecnicamente não existe).
4. Esse `if ( escolha==3)` dentro do `default` está muito esquisito. Se quer fazer algo quando a escolha é 3, monte um `case` para isso. E coloque tudo lá, não precisa ter o outro `if` igual logo abaixo. É mais esquisito o `while` executar até que a `escolha` seja 5. E outro detalhe, você só precisa de um `system ("cls");` em todo seu código.
5. Esta forma de verificar se há espaço no vetor para colocar novos dados é extremamente falho. Você precisaria inicializar os dados com NULL e verificar isto.
6. Esta variável `espaco` é completamente desnecessária. Se achar espaço vago no vetor, você processa a inclusão ali naquele `if`, não precisa criar um algoritmo confuso.
7. Se está usando um vetor, precisa usar um índice na variável. No `scan` provavelmente você queria fazer `&vetor[i]->nome`. E no outro provavelmente `&vetor[i].telefone` (se está usando um `int` e não um ponteiro para `int`, teria que usar o operador `.` e não o operador `->`.
8. Depois no `printf()` está usando o operador errado novamente. Você está mandando imprimir o ponteiro quando quer imprimir o conteúdo apontado por ele, assim: `&vetor[x]->nome`.
9. No `printf()` teria que usar os especificadores `%s` e `%d`. O mesmo erro foi cometido no `scanf()`.
10. Você está usando a variável `x` no *loop* mas ela não varia, quem está variando é a `i`.
11. Você só pode dizer que o vetor está vazio se passar por todo o `for` e nenhum item for impresso, não pode dizer isto enquanto está dentro do `for`.

Tem uma série de pequenos outros detalhes que não farão tanta diferença, como variáveis não usadas, ora usar o `MAX` e ora usar um literal `3` que nem bate com o valor atual de `MAX`, inconsistência entre uso de ponteiro e *array*, comentários que dizem fazer algo que não é real, etc. que fazem seu código ficar esquisito ou até errado.

Eu não fiz uma análise muito profunda. Pode ter mais erros ou eu posso ter entendido algo errado. Você precisa melhorar por partes.

Acho que ajudei bastante, mais do que isto só se fizer para você e tenho certeza de que você quer fazer por conta própria.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: bigown muito obrigado pela ajuda, com certeza quero termina-lo por conta própria, tenho q aprender neh rsrs...vou tentar corrigir os erros, qualquer duvida posto aki novamente...mto obrigado mesmo abços

Comment: @Zuul dor de cabeça é fazer algo ficar bom em todos *browsers* e versões :)

Comment: @bigown Isso não se chama dor de cabeça, chama-se CSS :D

Comment: bigown adotei a suas recomendações, agora está bem melhor, porém o programa não consegue guardar as inf de um pessoa, quando peço pra ele digitar novamente e depois imprimir ele imprimi somente o ultimo registro ele apaga os demais.

Comment: @MuriloSilva abra outra pergunta colocando o código atual e mostrando onde está o problema. Se deu eu tento responder, mas outra pessoa poderá responder também. Depois seria legal você fazer o [tour] do site para ver que você pode aceitar uma resposta como a mais correta que te ajudou e mais tarde quando tiver mais reputação poderá votar em todas as respostas que ajudaram de alguma forma.